# Event / detect when your DLL gets loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Imagine there is a `MainLibrary.dll` that's [dynamically loading other helper DLLs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx). This is a design change for us and for this to work, we need to bootstrap the process by registering the `AssemblyResolve` callback.

This is simple to do when there is a single point of entry (eg: `Main()`) but in our case, `MainLibrary.dll` has multiple entry points. We'd want to avoid introducing an explicit `Init()` call since that would break the existing client-library API ("*You must now call Init() before calling DoSomeWork()*").

So is there a way for a library to know when it's been loaded or about to be used? That way we can latch onto that to perform our registration there, maintaining the client-library interface as before this dynamic loading change.

Comment: [`AppDomain.AssemblyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx) Is triggered after an assembly is loaded to memory for the first time. So you should be able to add your bootstrapping code in an event handler.

Comment: @Xenolightning - I think `AssemblyLoad` is too late as DeepSpace101 wants to know about it from assembly that is not loaded yet and hence can't listen to any "loading" events.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way for assembly to know when it is loaded (unlike in native code where `DllMain` get called on load).

You will need to reorganize your code to know when to load other binaries if they can't be loaded with default load rules.

Cheap way is to provide (maybe even automatically generated) layer of interface/objects wrapper implementations that will simply enforce loading of dependencies before calling into your actual API.